# Accidentally Corrupted Yaru Theme. How to reinstall. Please Help

Tags: 20.04, themes

When i installed K Desktop Environment.i accidentally corrupted my yaru theme.How do i reinstall it or can i recover it. i tried to reinstall gtk but that also did not work

Comment: Changing the DE on an installed system can be extremely messy. This is why most distros, including Ubuntu, come in many different versions. Ubuntu's [flavours](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) have different desktop environments so that you can install the DE you want during system installation. While @N0rbert has an answer to the question that you asked, it might not solve the actual problems you are experiencing since installing a DE installs several dozen packages-many of which could conflict with your current DE. If you are new to Ubuntu you may find it easier to reinstall the system.

Comment: currently i have removed the conflicting packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following commands should reinstall all Yaru-related packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -l | grep -i yaru | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: thank you this worked.